# Rendering 3D images from 2+ imagesets + DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, orthophoto

The most general way of rendering a 3D model in QGIS is by using QGIS2threejs. It works by adding a single layer raster-image/orthophoto and exaggerating a DEM, usually a 1 band raster.

Depending on the image quality, the rendering can become more or less detailed, and looking besides the algorithm which is making a 'melting' rendering of the exaggerated DEM, the plugin does the job very well!

However my concern is that if I zoom in on the slope, navigating the viewing camera so that I see it horisontally, the image of the model, isn't very well rendered. Not surprising because the algorithm does not take in consideration that the cameralens was vertically above the point, not horisontally from the point.

So my question is how it could be possible to render an image that merges 2+ imagesets from different angles and rendering a 3D model that is photorealistic from several angles because of the additional cameralenses?

I recon that Streetview does it, so somewhere the algorithm must be existing, but is there a tool available from eg. QGIS or ESRI perhaps, that can do the job?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the helpers out there.

Photogrammetry is what brought me further down the road.

[Wiki Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry)